# E_PRIVILEGE_DENIED result for GenerateKeyEvent() in Thread

Tags: tizen

Created a Service app to simulate keys. Override the Thread class to MyThread class to simulate keys.

Code Snippet:

```
Object*
MyThread::Run(void)
{
    AppLog("MyThread :: Object* Run(void)");

    Tizen::Ui::KeyCode keyToSimulate = Tizen::Ui::KEY_A;

    result r = Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(Tizen::Ui::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_PRESSED, keyToSimulate);
    AppLog("KEY_EVENT_TYPE_PRESSED [%d] and result :: %s", keyToSimulate, GetErrorMessage(r));

    r = Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent(Tizen::Ui::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_RELEASED, keyToSimulate);
    AppLog("KEY_EVENT_TYPE_RELEASED [%d] and result :: %s", keyToSimulate, GetErrorMessage(r));

    return null;
}
```

In OnAppInitialized() created a Thread instance and started as below:

```
mpMyThread = new MyThread;

mpMyThread->Construct();

mpMyThread->Start();
```

result of GenerateKeyEvent shows E_PRIVILEGE_DENIED. My question here does MyThread class has the privileges same as parent? If not how can i send events in MyThread class?

Thanks,

Anil

Comment: did you tried to send this event in OnUserReceivedN()

Answer (score 0):

Tizen::Ui::SystemUtil::GenerateKeyEvent() is privileged API. You should have 'http://tizen.org/privilege/inputmanager' in your app's manifest.xml. And the API's privilege level is 'platform'. You also should have a platform level privileged signature to sign your app.

Comment: Though i have added these privileges i am facing this problem.